# How to connect mongolab to django?

Tags: django, mongodb, mlab

I am creating a app in django and I want to fetch data from mongolab.
But,I don't know how to connect mongolab to django.
I had connect mongodb to django but now I want to connect with mongolab.
How to do this?

I have used this in my setting.py file,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin', 
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'djangotoolbox',
    'app'
)
```

And in DATABASE:,

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
       'NAME': '*****',
       'USER': '*****',
       'PASSWORD': '******',
       'HOST': 'ds129469.mongolab.com',
       'PORT': '26469' 
    }
}
```

And after running command, python manage.py runserver 
I get following error,

```
life@life-All-Series:~/mongo/env1/project7/project$ python manage.py runrver
/home/life/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangotoolbox/db/utils.py:1: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The django.db.backends.util module has been renamed. Use django.db.backends.utils instead.
  from django.db.backends.util import format_number

/home/life/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangotoolbox/db/utils.py:1: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The django.db.backends.util module has been renamed. Use django.db.backends.utils instead.
  from django.db.backends.util import format_number

Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fbad4b24c08>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 168, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 191, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 49, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/home/life/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mongodb_engine/base.py", line 179, in table_names
    return self.connection.database.collection_names()
  File "/home/life/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 488, in collection_names
    ReadPreference.PRIMARY) as (sock_info, slave_okay):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/home/life/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 699, in _socket_for_reads
    with self._get_socket(read_preference) as sock_info:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/home/life/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 663, in _get_socket
    server = self._get_topology().select_server(selector)
  File "/home/life/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 121, in select_server
    address))
  File "/home/life/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 97, in select_servers
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: ds129469.mongolab.com:29469: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```